# POSTGRES - LIMIT 1 DESC for each ID in WHERE IN

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Problem:
I have a table where there are several rows with same code but different date, I also have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE CODE IN ('action', 'comedy')
```

Question:
How can I return row with latest date FOR EACH code in the list and limit it to 1 since there can be duplicates:

[image]

so it returns just ID 1 and 4.

Something like

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE CODE IN ('action', 'comedy') DESC LIMIT 1
```

**but for each code**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Postgres, use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (CODE) m.*
FROM movies m
WHERE m.CODE IN ('action', 'comedy')
ORDER BY m.CODE, m.start_date DESC;
```

`DISTINCT ON` is a Postgres extension.  It returns a result set with one row per unique combination of values of the expressions in parentheses (like `GROUP BY` keys in that respect).  The particular row is determined by the `ORDER BY` clause.  The unique keys come first and the rest of the keys define "which" row.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT code, MAX(start_date)
FROM movies
GROUP BY code
```

Comment: This won't return the id field (or fields other than code and start_date). The OP asks for SELECT *, so this won't work :(